# x86 assembly to programmatically determine endianess

Tags: assembly, x86, endianness

I understand that Intel x86 is little endian.  However, how would I write assembly to programmatically determine the endianess of a processor?

Comment: While you could do that, that doesn't make sense. Since you're writing in some assembly language, you already know the answer.

Comment: Some processors have configurable endianness (ARM), though. If the code needs to be re-usable, that might explain it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store a word that has different values for each of it’s two bytes (`0x0001`, for example).  Load a byte from the same address and check to see which byte of the original word it matches.

Answer (score 1):

Implement it in C because C is portable to other architectures. We already know Intel is little endian. There is no use of implement it in assembly. This example return 1 if **Little endian** ditected otherwise return 0.

```
int host_endian()
{
    static const union {
        uint16_t    i;
        uint8_t     c[2];
    } test = { 0x1234 };

    return (test.c[0] == 0x34) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: If you store `0x0001`, you can `return test.c[0]` without a compare.  But note that C doesn't guarantee that the host is either big or little endian for types wider than 2 `char`s.  For example, [PDP-endian is a real possibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle).  But this does determine the 2-byte endianness.  (It only compiles on machines that support `uint8_t` and `uint16_t`, though, so probably not on many esoteric machines with stuff like 9-bit "bytes" or 36-bit words.)  Of course, a lot of code doesn't even try to be portable to historical machines like that.